# Anchor WPF control to the right

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

This has to be fairly simple but my search is heavily disturbed by people trying to stretch a control (using Anchor.Left | Anchor.Right previously in Winforms).

That's unrelated, I just want to anchor a control to the right.

What I have is this:

```
|--------|
|        |
|  Foobar|
|--------|
```

I can do that using HorizontalAlignment, a grid or a number of other ways. But it breaks if I resize the control.

I want:

```
|----|
|    |
|obar|
|----|
```

(that is - anchor on the right.. Don't touch that distance to the edge. Move the left side out of view)

Instead I get this:

```
|----|
|    |
|Foob|
|----|
```

(the left side of my content won't move out of view).

I'm sure there's an easy solution to this, but so far I cannot convince WPF that it should damage/cut off the left side of my controls, no matter what.

---

Okay, I was cheating and made it too simple I guess. What I really have is a list of rectangles (here represented by an X):

```
|---------|
|     XXXX|
|---------|
```

This is an ItemsControl with a StackPanel inside, containing (more or less only) Rectangles. The expectation stays the same though: Anchor the whole thing to the right, damage/scroll out the left side only when I resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HorizontalAlignment="Right" is definitely the way to go and it even works if you re size the control.

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="FooBarrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrttttttttttttttt"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
```

Comment: This is not what I want. As far as I can see this is a) what I'm already doing and b) not behaving correctly when I resize (yes, it's right aligned. Until the contents doesn't fit the screen anymore, then the _left_ side is kept and the right side is damaged).

Comment: Okay - after fiddling around a lot and creating simpler and simpler testcases: You are perfectly correct. My problem was embedding things inside of a ScrollViewer, it seems. It works now by 'reverting' everything: ScrollViewer.FlowDirection RightToLeft and StackPanel inside using implicit HorizontalAlignment = Left.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm doing too much here, but I know this works:

```
  <DockPanel>  
    <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Right">
      <TextBlock Canvas.Right="0">FooBar</TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
    <Grid></Grid>
  </DockPanel>
```

Without the Canvas it will do as you say, ie cut off the right side.

You also have to set Canvas.Right. Thus the canvas gets the width of the Textblock but gets cut off on the left.

EDIT:

this also works and probably is simpler

```
  <DockPanel>  
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right">FooBar</TextBlock>        
    <Grid></Grid>
  </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Okay, so I was oversimplifying. I don't have just one Textblock that I care about, I have an ItemsControl, using a StackPanel filled with Rectangles. Think horizontal bar chart, multiple rectangles. I tried putting the ItemsControl or StackPanel into a DockPanel, but the behavior seems to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try sticking your control inside a DockPanel and set the attached property DockPanel.Dock="Right" on your control.